# Open files from AWS instance in text editor

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, atom-editor

bit of a beginners question, so apologies.

A friend has created an instance on AWS which I have connected to, but how do I open up the files in text editor? ordinarily I'd just 
`code .` or  `atom .` but if I do that I get an error: 
`-bash: atom: command not found`

Help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Your question lacks suficient detail for a good answer. Yushould add how you connect, your OS and the OS on the AWS instance. The easiest way is probably to dhare the filesystem and edit the file on your pc (using nfs, samba, sshfs or equibvalent for your OS.). The alternative is to install this software and run it renotely, exporting the terminal. This is probablynot great. Of-course, maybe tjis shoykd all be done licallt using GIT or some other versioning solution.

Comment: HI @davidgo thanks for responding. I'm using mac OS. It's a HyperLedger Fabric project we're working on. I would have thought it would be better to use GIT too, but was told to connect via the instance on AWS - got stuck there after.  Do you think it's possible to use git? I don't really know enough about it all.

Comment: I cant advise authoratively because I dont have a mac nor do I have knowledge of Hyperledger, but I would look at using sshfs to mount the AWS filrsystem on your Mac (over SSH) then do ypur edits using software on the Mac. I cant comment on why they are not using git which would seem to be a best practice.